# JQuery forEach function works only one way

Tags: jquery, tabs, each

I am creating my own tabbing function for jumping from one div to another based on user selection. Basically it's very similar to JQueryUI's Tabs. 
The only problem I have is with the "next" and "prev" buttons - I wrote a function that changes the variable classes based on arguments ('prev' or 'next') and while it works perfectly fine for 'next', it fails for 'prev'...and I have no idea why, as for me it all looks fine.

HTML:

```
    <div class="ar-tabbed-content">
    <div class="ar-tab ar-tab-1"><p>tab1</p></div>
    <div class="ar-tab ar-tab-2"><p>tab2</p></div>
    <div class="ar-tab ar-tab-3"><p>tab3</p></div>
    <div class="ar-tab ar-tab-4"><p>tab4</p></div>
    <div class="ar-tab ar-tab-5"><p>tab5</p></div>


<div class="ar-tabbed-content--nav">
    <ul>
<!--<li class="tab-prev"><a href="#prev">Prev</a></li>-->
    <li><a href="#ar-tab-1">global market</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ar-tab-2">slide 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ar-tab-3">slide 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ar-tab-4">slide 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ar-tab-5">slide 5</a></li>
  <!--  <li class="tab-next"><a href="#next">Next</a></li>-->
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    (function() {
        var tabsContainer = $('.ar-tabbed-content'),
            allTabs = tabsContainer.find('.ar-tab'),
            tabsQty = allTabs.length,
            firstTab = tabsContainer.find('.ar-tab-1'),
            lastTab = tabsContainer.find('.ar-tab-' + (tabsQty)),
            tabsNav = tabsContainer.find('.ar-tabbed-content--nav');

        tabsContainer.find('ul').prepend('<li class="tab-prev"><a href="#prev">Prev</a></li>');
        tabsContainer.find('ul').append('<li class="tab-next"><a href="#next">Next</a></li>');

        var tabsNavBtn = tabsNav.find('ul li a');

        firstTab.addClass('active');
        firstTab.show();

        console.log(lastTab);

        function prevNext(prevOrNext) {
            allTabs.each(function(i, el) {
                var elem = $(el);

                if (elem.hasClass('active') || elem.hasClass('active2')) {
                    elem.removeClass('active');
                    elem.removeClass('active2');
                    elem.hide();

                    var nextElem;
                    var tabNo,
                        nextTab;

                    if (prevOrNext == 'next') {
                        tabNo = 'ar-tab-' + (tabsQty);
                        nextTab = firstTab;
                        nextElem = tabsContainer.find('.ar-tab-' + (i + 2));
                    } else {
                        tabNo = 'ar-tab-1';
                        nextTab = lastTab;
                        nextElem = tabsContainer.find('.ar-tab-' + i);
                    }


                    console.log(nextElem);
                    console.log(tabNo);
                    console.log(nextTab);

                    if (elem.hasClass(tabNo)) {
                        nextTab.addClass('active2');
                        nextTab.show();
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        nextElem.addClass('active2');
                        nextElem.show();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });

        };


        tabsNavBtn.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var thisBtn = $(this),
                btnHref = thisBtn.attr('href'),
                btnValue = btnHref.substring(1);

            if (btnValue == 'prev') {
                console.log('prev');
                prevNext('prev');

            }
            if (btnValue == 'next') {
                prevNext('next');

            } else {
                var tabClass = '.' + btnValue,
                    tabToShow = tabsContainer.find(tabClass);
                allTabs.removeClass('active');
                allTabs.removeClass('active2');
                allTabs.hide();
                tabToShow.addClass('active');
                tabToShow.addClass('active2');
                tabToShow.show('fade', 300);
            }

        });


    })();



});
```

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y925hy1p/

Comment: Could you provide a sample on http://jsfiddle.net/ which show us the problem ?

Comment: Sure, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/y925hy1p/      As you can see, tabbing works fine as well as "next" button, but "prev" fails... any tip will be useful.

Comment: I think your script is too complex for the expected behavior. You could attempt to rewrite it without the `each` function, and with using jQuery `next` and `prev` function after selecting the current displayed element. you could also use a plugin to do this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact your error is really simple : You only miss an `else` in your click function.
When debugging, I found that your `prevNext` function was working as expected, but then in your click function without the `else` statement, you remove the added classes.

```
if (btnValue == 'prev') {
    console.log('prev');
    prevNext('prev');
} else if (btnValue == 'next') {
    prevNext('next');
}
```